# Why is Value a equals("Value of a") false

Tags: java, android, boolean, equals

I have a variable `error`. It has the value: `#2002`.
But `error.euqals("#2002")` is false. Why?

```
Log.d("TestValueError", error);
Log.d("TestErrorIs#2002", String.valueOf(error.equals("#2002")));
```

> 2020-03-27 07:17:03.435 6684-6684/e.marco.test D/TestValueError: #2002
>   2020-03-27 07:17:03.435 6684-6684/e.marco.test D/TestErrorIs#2002: false

The variable `error` is initialized by a `HTTP Request`

Comment: It should always return true unless your error value is something else. System.out.println(String.valueOf("#2002".equals("#2002"))) --> always return true

Comment: Yes I know but it doesn't. If I initialized error manuel then it is true

Comment: print error value first, see if there are spaces or some other special characters.

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable `error` is not a `String` you need to do `error.toString().equals("#2002")` as in:

```
Log.d("TestErrorIs#2002", String.valueOf(error.toString().equals("#2002")))
```

Better yet, call the `error` method that returns the error code.